# classes with a lot of members

Tags: c++, class, constructor, member, class-design

I am attempting to create a D&D encounter simulator.
I have therefore created a class called "Actor" to emulate the behaviour of the players and the monsters. The problem is that while the class for the moment only have 3 member variable, as the simulation gets more accurate it will become necessary to add more member variables to best simulate the stats of the monsters and player e.g. strength, dexterity etc. (possibly more than 10 member variables)
This leads to a constructor with a lot of parameters so the question then becomes; Is there a better way to organize this data, since it can all vary with every instance of the actor class?

Right now the user is required to type in all the states by hand, though I have plans to make file reading for monsters accessible later since monster stats only vary with monster type (dragon, skeleton etc.)

Note: These stats are very important and used to calculate the outcome of every action the "Actor" class can take in the encounter.

**EDIT:**
A lot of people suggest using inheritance, but the fact is that (Monsters and Players) never have different stats, the monsters like the players are controlled by a player (The Game Master) This is a tabletop game and the simulator is supposed to help the game master balance encounter's ahead of a real game.

**Actor.h**

```
#ifndef actor_h_
#define actor_h_

#include "dice.h"

class Actor
{
  private:
    signed int hp;
    signed int ac; // Armor Class
    signed int dmg;
    
  public:
    Actor( signed int hp, int ac, int dmg);
    ~Actor();

    signed int getHP( void );
    signed int getAC( void );
    signed int getDmg( void );
    void setHP(signed int newHP);
    void setAC(signed int newAC);
    void setDmg(signed int newDmg);

    void attack(Actor* target);
};
#endif
```

**Actor Constructor**

```
Actor::Actor(signed int hp, signed int ac, signed int dmg)
{
  this->hp = hp;
  this->ac = ac;
  this->dmg = dmg;
}
Actor::~Actor(){}
```

Comment: To me, it looks like Actor should be a virtual class - with "PC", "NPC" and "Monster" classes inheriting it... because not all of them will want the same parameters.

Comment: Well you might be right, but the thing is that in D&D combat, monsters and PC use the same stats so they require the same parameters and NPC are not a factor since they are controlled by PC's during combat also utilizing stats equivalent to those of a PC

Comment: There's a book called iOS Swift Game Development Cookbook which discusses various strategies to handle this kind of situation.  The information is good, even if you'd have to abstract it from the platform & language.  (I know, you probably aren't programming for iOS, and you're not programming in Swift.)  Maybe there is a "game development cookbook" for your platform and in C++.

Comment: @MortenKristensen so what you're saying is that there's a "CombatActor" which has all the combat stats - and then other types of actor

Comment: @UKMonkey The Game is a TableTop RPG (The game is not played on a PC), where the story and NPC is controlled by a game master, inside the game the players can happen upon enemies in combat encounters. The only goal is to give the game master a tool for simulating the result of these encounters so as to make sure the encounters are not too easy or too difficult.
All other aspects of the game is irrelevant to the simulator.

Comment: @UKMonkey
So the game master can input the stats of the players and the monsters and the simulator will return some statistics, like chance of player death, the chance of party wipe, average number of hits, average damage dealt per turn etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This leads to a constructor with a lot of parameters so the question then becomes; Is there a better way to organize this data, since it can all vary with every instance of the actor class?
> Right now the user is required to type in all the states by hand, though I have plans to make file reading for monsters accessible later since monster stats only vary with monster type (dragon, skeleton etc.)

It sounds like this question is less about how to engineer the OOP, but rather how to define all the stats for the program without it being hugely cumbersome.

Reading stats from files is a good idea. You could represent them in one or more JSON files and use [Nlohmann's JSON library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) to read it into your program. You'll still have to write code that says how your program should use the read JSON data, and of course you need to write the JSON in the first place---no free lunch. But it could nevertheless be helpful for organizing the program.

Another thought: for actors like an army of orcs, or wherever there are multiple instances of the same kind, a useful approach could be to define an orc [factory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) that creates an orc actor and its stats. The factory could pseudorandomly vary speed, strength, etc. so that each orc is personalized a little different without having to manually write stats for each instance.

Comment: This sounds about right, for what I need. I don't have any JSON Experience, but I guess there is a first time for everything. I like the suggestion for a factory to "individualize" small minions like orc and such.
If I do decide to use factories like that, would I then need to make distinct factory function for every creature or do you think it would be possible to make a factory that read in some stats from a creature file and then tweaked them a bit by randomly adjusting it by a small amount within well-defined boundaries?

Comment: Yes absolutely, it is possible and I agree a good idea to make a factory that can generically make multiple kinds of creatures. The factory could take as an input arg the file name for a creature stats file, then you can pass different files to it to make different kinds of creatures. JSON was just a suggestion for a way to represent stats in the file, but certainly there is more than one right answer. Do what works for you! =)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves a lot of my problems if I can get it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

As you bring up the example of stats yourself, those could go in a

```
struct StatsBlock {
    int str, dex, con, /*others*/;
};
```

You can then either source them from static class variables or static methods:

```
class Skeleton : public Actor {
...
public:
static inline const StatsBlock = { 13, 8, ... };
static StatsBlock rollStats() { ... );
};
```

As a bonus, this also gives you a central place to apply or remove effects that change the stats temporarily, like equipping a "Ring of +1 strength" or being hit with a spell like Polymorph.

Comment: That's a great idea! brilliant.
Do you think it would be a viable Idea to use your example but give the user the option of entering custom stats? such as to reflect that players from different games might have chosen to distribute their stats differently thus accounting for player choice?
If so would that require it's own separate implementation of the actor class? (maybe subclass to Actor).

Comment: Sure. Just create a `StatsBlock createFromPlayerInput()` and pass the result to your `PC` constructor.

Comment: Great, this is definitely worth looking into, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

It's a basic concept of Polymorphism in C++, and I would suggest to start from reading about it

You can have for example your base class Actor will contain the basic information that every entity in your emulator has (monster, player etc.)

Then you can create a Monster and a Player class, which derive from your Actor class. Those will have their own unique information (tooth size, breaths under water, fly etc..)

If you want to dynamically create new stats for your player as the emulation goes on, I would suggest using smart pointers to hold these members for memory optimization.

Comment: Polymorphism is often overused and leads to many problems. Especially in such a use-case the different properties of actor types, could overlap in ways that don't fit polymorphism very well. Often compositing is a better solution in such a case.

Comment: My question seems to be ambiguous, let me clarify.
The stats of the monsters and the players do not differ, there is no difference in their
stats. only the fact that during an actual game, the PC would be controlled by humans
and the monsters would be controlled by another human (The Game Master)

With that out of the way, your note on smart pointers is great for manipulating stats so I will keep that in mind, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have a parameter for each property of the stats of the actor in the constructor of the actor you can consider having a separate stats object and pass an instance of that stats to the constructor:

```
struct ActorStats {
    signed int hp;
    signed int ac; // Armor Class
    signed int dmg;
}

struct Actor {
  Actor(ActorStats stats) : stats_(std::move(stats)) {}

  signed int getHP( void );
  signed int getAC( void );
  signed int getDmg( void );
  void setHP(signed int newHP);
  void setAC(signed int newAC);
  void setDmg(signed int newDmg);

  void attack(Actor* target);

  protected:
    ActorStats stats_;
};
```

You could then have different strategies of creating an actor, like reading from a save file, or from a preset:

```
ActorStats read_stats_from_file() {
    ActorStats stats;
    // some reading logic

    stats.hp = // value read from file

    return stats;
}

Actor create_actor() {
    ActorStats stats = read_stats_from_file();
    Actor actor(stats);

    return Actor;
}
```

That way you don't need to implement a getter/setter for each stats, and don't need to use `friend` for the functions that should initialize the stats. But the raw values are still protected, as soon as they are passed to the `Actor`.